# Make a HTTP/1.1 GET request in android

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am trying to request data from an API.The requirements of the API are given below:

> Base-URL for our API is https://api.openload.co/1 (note the 1 for
>   version 1 behind the /)
>
> All requests to the API shall be HTTP/1.1 GET
>
> Please make sure to use the API with https only.
>
> Most requests require a API Login & API Key, you can find both in the
>   User Panel at the "User Settings" Tab. Response is json, structure is
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> {    "status": <status-code>,
>
>     "msg": "<informational message. might vary, use the status code in your code!>",
>
>     "result": <result of the request. varies depending on the request>
> }
> ```

I'm using the following method to get the json response:

```
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {

        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect()

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
            // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
            // could be thrown.
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

But I'm recieveing the response code 403.
I'm using the below url to test it:
https://api.openload.co/1/account/info?login={login}&key={key}

When requesting from chrome, the response is obtained in form of a file.Could that be causing the issue as I'm expecting a json response String and the server is returning a file containing the json?

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong as if I use the same url in chrome I'm getting the json response but can''t seem to get the response via code.

Comment: try urlConnection.getResponseCode() == "200"

Comment: the getResponseCode returns a integer response code,so I'm not sure how one can compare it to a String.

Comment: Ok, so you Can create a file log on your server and check if all parameter are correct

Answer (score 0):

A response of 403 means you either submitted credentials improperly or you submitted invalid credentials. So, there seem to be two obvious places that could be causing your issue here.

Firstly, are you properly setting your login and key into the URL at the substitution points?

Secondly, are you sure you are a valid and active login and key?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I checked.As i stated above using the same credentials I'm able to get a response from chrome but not from the code.

Comment: I suggest you place a few log statements to verify this. A 403 is rather unambiguous in its causes

Comment: Is there a way to specify that the get request be made via HTTP/1.1?

Comment: In order to return a 403 you have to have already successfully established an HTTP connection. I'm telling ya you aren't submitting your creds properly.

Comment: At the risk of repetition if I wasn't passing the credentials correctly,when requesting from chrome using the same url format and credentials shouldn't I get the same error code?

Comment: One thing I would like to specify, when requesting from chrome, the response is obtained in form of a file.Could that be causing the issue as I'm expecting a json response String and the server is returning a file containing the json?